# Text input fadeToggle jQuery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple todo list, I have the code posted below so you can run it and see exactly what I'm talking about.
I want to be able to click on the heart icon inside of the h1 and toggle the todo list "text" input.

I am almost positive my code is correct, yet obviously not because, clicking on the heart icon does nothing.
I am using jQuery 3.2.1 through a cdn and font awesome 5.

I tried selecting the fa-heart icon and giving it the argument that when clicked to toggle the fade i/o for text inputs. It didn't work and I am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
// Check Off Specific Todos By Clicking
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

//Click on X to delete Todo
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    //grabbing new todo text from input
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    //create a new li and add to ul
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>")
  }
});

$(".fa-heart").click(function() {
  $("input[type='text']").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 360px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #d4d1ca;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.completed {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

h1 {
  background: #abc3a8;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background: #abc3a8/* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c9b7b3, #97a794);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c9b7b3, #97a794);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

li {
  background-color: #c9b7b3;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abc3a8;
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
  border: 3px solid #abc3a8;
  outline: none;
}

.fa-heart {
  float: right;
}

span {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Honey-do List</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/honeyDew.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.3/js/all.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Honey-do List <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="New Honey Do!">
    <ul>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Go get Milk</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Take the dogs out</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Buy flowers</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/honeyDew.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi, its working fine from myside. whats the issue you are facing.

Comment: This has something to do with the script tag I used in the header for fontawesome.

Comment: the heart when clicked doesn't toggle or fade out the text input

Comment: i run your code at my side. Its working fine. input text is toggling and records is also adding on enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put div around your icon 
Click event will not work with  tag

`Honey-do List`

```js
// Check Off Specific Todos By Clicking
$("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

//Click on X to delete Todo
$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    //grabbing new todo text from input
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    //create a new li and add to ul
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>")
  }
});

$(".fa-heart").click(function() {
  alert('test');
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 360px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #d4d1ca;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.completed {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

h1 {
  background: #abc3a8;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background: #abc3a8/* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c9b7b3, #97a794);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #c9b7b3, #97a794);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

li {
  background-color: #c9b7b3;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #666;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #abc3a8;
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 13px 13px 13px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #d4d1ca;
  border: 3px solid #abc3a8;
  outline: none;
}

.fa-heart {
  float: right;
}

span {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

li:hover span {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Honey-do List</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/honeyDew.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.3/js/all.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Honey-do List <div class="fa-heart"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div></h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="New Honey Do!">
    <ul>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Go get Milk</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Take the dogs out</li>
      <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Buy flowers</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/honeyDew.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought I was going to have to accept that I couldn't use Font Awesome 5.  The div makes a lot of sense. Thank you!